# C++ list iterators incompatible error

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I'm new to iterators in C++ and I'm facing problem with incompatible iterators. I've spent on this over 5 hours and still I can't figure out why it's not compatible or what I did wrong. I'm sure, I messed up iterator's operators or something close to it.

Iterator header

```
class iterator : public std::iterator < std::input_iterator_tag, Agent > {
    list<Agent> agentList;
    list<Agent>::iterator it;
public:
    iterator(list<Agent>** env, int rows, int cols);
    void operator ++(int);
    bool operator ==(const iterator& a) const;
    bool operator !=(iterator& a) const;
    Agent& operator*();
};
```

Iterator implementation

```
Prostredi::iterator::iterator(list<Agent>** env, int rows, int cols) {
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            for (list<Agent>::iterator it = env[r][c].begin(); it != env[r][c].end(); it++) {
                agentList.push_front(*it);
            }
        }
    }
    it = agentList.begin();
}

void Prostredi::iterator::operator++(int) {
    it++;
}

Agent& Prostredi::iterator::operator*() {
    return *it;
}

bool Prostredi::iterator::operator== (Prostredi::iterator& a) const {
    return !(it != a.it);
}

bool Prostredi::iterator::operator!= (Prostredi::iterator& a) const {
    return a.it != it; // Here it crashes
}
```

I'm calling it in this for-cycle. It crashes before first iteration while trying to compare `it != p.dejEntityEnd()`.

```
void Stav::napln(const Prostredi & p) {
    for (auto it = p.dejEntityBegin(); it != p.dejEntityEnd(); it++) {
        agenti.push_back((*it).vypocitejNovyStav(p));
    }
}

Prostredi::iterator Prostredi::dejEntityBegin() const {
    return Prostredi::iterator(env, rows, cols);
}

Prostredi::iterator Prostredi::dejEntityEnd() const {
    Prostredi::iterator it = Prostredi::iterator(env, rows, cols);
    Prostredi::iterator::it = agentList.end();
    return it;
}
```

Project has several classes and header files and everything is essential for correct setup, so it's hard to abstract the problem without leaving important info. If you need more information, I'll gladly reply or you can get my full project here (breakpoints are already set): https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9lsle7seiqz2wgj/AABJAXRXo350AhVmm-OqRSOqa
[image]

Comment: `list<Agent>** env`  -- Any reason for this type of a construct in a C++ program?  I'm sure a container class would eliminate the need for double pointers.

Comment: Yes, I have a reason for that. Basically what I've tried to do was 2D array, with lists inside as a 3rd dimension. So I can access any coordinates in a array via [x][y] and then get all agents on that position from a list. That shouldn't be problem.

Comment: A 2D Array?  `std::vector<std::vector<list<Agent>>>`.  No need for pointers.

Comment: It's surely possible option but we were taught in school to do it via double pointers. I don't like it either, but it's only way I know it works. I've never used vector before, even when I know what it is and how it probably works. My program is almost done, so I won't redo it all, I would like to solve the problem with iterators :/

Answer (score 0):

Every `Prostredi::iterator` object contains its own unique `std::list<Agent>`.  You may only compare iterators that are from the same `std::list`.  So even `p.dejEntityBegin() != p.dejEntityEnd()` is Undefined Behavior.

To solve the problem it looks like you're trying to solve, you should have your iterator hold the original `list<Agent>**`, `rows`, and `cols`, along with some current position indices, and figure out how to increment/decrement with respect to those.

Comment: I think that my biggest problem is that I'm having issues correctly comprehend what should I compare in operator == and !=.